# z-index failing to work when all elements have position declared

Tags: css, z-index

I don't understand why in this example http://jsfiddle.net/BmnHZ/2/ the toggled blue div `.playlist` doesn't hide under the black `.menu` div. I set a position for both items but it doesn't take. How can I make `.playlist` stay behind `.menu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child with a z-index of 99 doesn't have a stacking order of less than a parent with a z-index of 100 BECAUSE the child, due to the fact that it is within a parent with a z-index of 100 is already "above" the parent's stacking order.

What you want to do is set z-index to -1 instead of 99 on the child.

It's kind of difficult for me to articulate, I hope you understand.